# Expected Squared Derivative of White Noise?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, microlocal-analysis

Let $W_t$ denote the continuous time Wiener process at time $t$. Then its time derivative $\xi(t):=\frac{d W_t}{dt}$ is white noise, and may be "seen" in the weak sense via inner products $\langle \xi, \psi\rangle = \langle W', \psi\rangle = \int \psi dW$ where $\psi$ is a test function.

From [this SO question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2422857/time-derivative-of-white-noise), I learned that we can make similar statements about the second derivative of the Wiener process, or the derivative of white noise. Namely,

$$
\langle W'', \psi\rangle = \langle W, \psi''\rangle = \int \psi''dW
$$

I am interested in a related quantity, namely $\langle (W'')^2, \psi\rangle $. Is there some way to express this random variable as an integral of (some function of) $\psi$ with respect to the Wiener process?

Comment: In general the square of a generalized random variable (Hida distribution) is not well defined. Still you can use the normalized square (using the Wick product).

Comment: Let me known if you are interested in a full answer

Comment: @Chaos I am insanely interested in a full answer :)

Comment: Nice, I'll try to put together an answer asap. By the way notice that the first formula should be $\langle W',\varphi\rangle= \int \varphi dW $

Comment: @Chaos No rush, friend. I believe I've implemented your suggestion.

Comment: @Chaos but if you happen to have the time... :)